# Ruby regex checks string for variations of pattern of same length

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I was wondering how you construct the regular expression to check if the string has a variation of a pattern with the same length. Say the string is "door boor robo omanyte" how do I return the words that have the variation of [door]?

Comment: What do you mean by variation of `[door]` ?

Comment: I mean changing the position of the word i.e. robo, boor, etc

Comment: "robo" is an *anagram* of "boor" (and vice-versa); both words contain the same letters but not in the same order. Do you want to return all groups of words in a string that contain anagrams of one another?  In the string "door sit its odor to", do you want to return `[["door", "odor"],["sit", "its"]]`?  Please edit your question to clarify (rather than trying to do that in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get all the possible words using [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation). Then you can scan for them in provided string. Here:

```
possible_words =  %w[d o o r].permutation.map &:join
# => ["door", "doro", "door", "doro", "droo", "droo", "odor", "odro", "oodr", "oord", "ordo", "orod", "odor", "odro", "oodr", "oord", "ordo", "orod", "rdoo", "rdoo", "rodo", "rood", "rodo", "rood"]

string = "door boor robo omanyte"
string.scan(possible_words.join("|"))
# => ["door"]

string = "door close rood example ordo"
string.scan(possible_words.join("|"))
# => ["door", "rood", "ordo"]
```

**UPDATE**

You can improve `scan` further by looking for word boundary. Here:

```
string = "doorrood example ordo"
string.scan(/"\b#{possible_words.join('\b|\b')}\b"/)
# => ["ordo"]
```

**NOTE**

As Cary correctly pointed out in comments below, this process is quite inefficient if you intend to find permutation for a fairly large string. However it should work fine for OP's example.

Comment: I'm not very good with regex what does /"\b#{possible_words.join('\b|\b')}\b"/ do?

Comment: also I know str=~/[aeiou]/ will return the index of the first instance of the regex but how can I get it to return all the instances of say the vowels that I'm looking for?

Comment: it will match only for words. Otherwise even a sting containing such pattern will be returned. Eg str = `doorrood example ordo`. If you dont put boundaries `\b`, even `doorrood` will be returned as it contains the pattern. However its not a desired result

Comment: This is terribly inefficient.  Suppose you were taking permutations of "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" (or any word having more than a few characters), do you realize how many permutations that would generate?

Comment: @user3043051 to return all instances use `scan`. Eg: `str.scan(/[aeiou]/)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree that's true. This answer is only good for small words.

Comment: What's the point of that when you can do it differently with no size limitations?

Answer (score 0):

If the comment I left on your question correctly interprets the question, you could do this:

```
str = "door sit its odor to"
str.split
   .group_by { |w| w.chars.sort.join }
   .values
   .select { |a| a.size > 1 }
  #=> [["door", "odor"], ["sit", "its"]]
```

This assumes all the letters are the same case.

If case is not important, just make a small change:

```
str = "dooR sIt itS Odor to"
str.split
   .group_by { |w| w.downcase.chars.sort.join }
   .values
   .select { |a| a.size > 1 }
  #=> [["dooR", "Odor"], ["sIt", "itS"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the fastest way to find this will be

```
word_a.chars.sort == word_b.chars.sort
```

since we are using the same characters inside the words

Answer (score 0):

IMO, some kind of iteration is definitely necessary to build a regular expression to match this one. Not using a regular expression is better too.

```
def variations_of_substr(str, sub)
    # Creates regexp to match words with same length, and 
    # with same characters of str.
    patt = "\\b" +  ( [ "[#{sub}]{1}" ] * sub.size ).join + "\\b"

    # Above alone won't be enough, characters in both words should 
    # match exactly.
    str.scan( Regexp.new(patt) ).select do |m|
        m.chars.sort == sub.chars.sort
    end
end

variations_of_substr("door boor robo omanyte", "door")
# => ["door"]
```